# window.print() not applying the css while converting html to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pdf

I am facing issue in print the pdf from html, I am using window.print() function but it is not applying the CSS, please someone help me into this issue

This is my code, here I am including CSS files at 3rd and 4th line but that does not working

CSS are in two to three files it is external css not inline, I tried adding @media print in those file but does not worked, let me know if i referencing those css files correctly or not in my below code, it is reactjs application

```
let mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=650,width=900,top=100,left=150');

mywindow.document.write(`<html><head><title>test</title>`);
mywindow.document.write( `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>` );
mywindow.document.write( `<link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>` );
mywindow.document.write(`</head><body>`);

mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("owtab").innerHTML);
mywindow.document.write(`</body></html>`);

mywindow.document.close();
mywindow.focus();

mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();
```

Comment: Have you provided the css required under media query for print ?

Comment: yes i did that , I am using two css files which I have referenced like this mywindow.document.write( <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="print"/> ); mywindow.document.write( <link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css" type="text/css"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the media query for `print` inorder to provide css when printing. Check this [Link](https://sympli.io/blog/a-quick-guide-to-css-for-printable-webpages/).

You can use as follows:

```
@media print {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: my css are in two to three files it is external css not inline, i tried adding @media print in those file but does not worked

Comment: No I mean what css are not getting applied ? Say if there is a class `.parent` and if you need some padding in it when getting printed, you need to give it as `@media print {.parent {padding: 20px}}` like this

Comment: not a single css class is applied while print, i have added @media print { all my css class here }

Comment: Are the css working when rendering on the UI? I mean is it not working only during print ?